# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_RETURN in C:\wamp\www\Nu-Bio\view_topic.php on line 77

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, return, syntax-error

Hello everybody~ I am getting this error (`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_RETURN in C:\wamp\www\Nu-Bio\view_topic.php on line 77`) when trying to run this little bit of code:

```
$idd = $rows['id'];
$thisql = "SELECT `locked` FROM `forum_question` WHERE `id` = '$idd'";
$mythisql = mysql_query($thisql);
$res1 = return($mythisql);
```

It's standalone, not in a function or anything. I'd give you more information, but I'm not sure what to give. I'm calling it with `if ($res1 == 0) {`. Thanks for any help I get!

(PS: I know I should be moving to mysqli. I WILL be doing that soon, please don't tell me to. I just want to make sure it works before changing it, as I'm almost done with my project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What should this "return" do? Anyway it's wrong here and is your error at line 77.

```
$res1 = return($mythisql);
```

Solution:

```
$res1 = $mythisql;
```

or

```
$res1 = mysql_query($thisql);
```

Comment: So, if this was the solution to your problem, you know what you have to do? ... ;)

Comment: I will, in five minutes :D (I dislike the 15 minute wait xD)

Comment: Didn't know there is one ... I always answer my own questions ;)

Comment: You, my friend, are smarter than I xD